# Android Studio doesn't let me use repeatOnLifecycle

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-lifecycle

I want to observe data inside my fragment from viewModel, but Android Studio keeps triggering this warning. Can someone help with this problem? Can this problem somehow be related to Android Studio Bumbleblee's update?
[image]

Comment: There is a good chance that this is a buggy Lint rule. You might consider creating a project that demonstrates the problem and [file an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/).

Comment: @CommonsWare - nope, that's a legit warning - you need to repeat the `viewLifecycleOwner` a second time inside the `launch` as per [the docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#restart).

Comment: I found this about the issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/209658963
It's probably a false positive. Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Just so this issue is found easier: The error is "The repeatOnLifecycle API should be used with viewLifecycleOwner" and the lint is supressed via @SuppressLint("UnsafeRepeatOnLifecycleDetector")

Comment: I had this come up in one file and not in another. Pretty inexplicable :(

Comment: @ianhanniballake Even after reading the docs, I'm unclear why viewLifecycleOwner needs to be used for fragments?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

When you write

```
viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
  repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
    // {code to collect from viewModel}
  }
}
```

The `repeatOnLifecycle` is an extension on a `LifecycleOwner` - here, you are implicitly using `this` - i.e., the Fragment's Lifeycle and most important **not** the Fragment View Lifecycle.

As seen in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#restart), you should explicitly be using `viewLifecycleOwner.repeatOnLifecycle`, which is exactly what the Lint check is telling you to use:

```
viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
  viewLifecycleOwner.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
    // {code to collect from viewModel}
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The JavaDoc of `repeatOnLifecycle()` should be updated since it still mentions `lifecycleScope.launch { repeatOnLifecycle(...) }`. Version 2.4.1 of `lifecycle-runtime-ktx`.

Comment: @SvenJacobs - the Javadoc clearly shows it is being used in an Activity, where that code is absolutely correct. Just because it is correct in an Activity, does not make it correct in a Fragment, hence this explicit Lint warning and the documentation I linked to.

Comment: Sorry I missed the part about Activity. But maybe the documentation could be extended with a Fragment example, too? ;)

Comment: Not sure why it is not implicitly using viewLifecycleOwner, we are calling repeatOnLifecycle from coroutine which is being launched with viewLifecycleOwner, so automatically calling repeatOnLifecycle inside the coroutine is done with viewLifecycleOwner

Comment: (Unintended trial and error): Adding viewLifecycleOwner. to EITHER of the lines (and not the other) drops the lint warning... Scratching my head as to why it's not a problem? And is it safe?